# Styling row of divs and bootstrap input group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row, styling, col

I am trying to make a fixed search bar on the bottom of the page. I want the search bar (row) to be broken up into three sections - 1) the actual search input box, (2) the middle div which will be a display box and (3) a collapsing advanced menu.

My first issue is that my columns do not appear on the same row. I have them broken in sizes of 3, 6 and 3 at all screen sizes but the second div never appears next to the first one. You can see an example here: [broken div](http://plnkr.co/edit/b4i0mYH1BiaWuKlke6zx?p=preview)
I highlighted the divs with a white border for easier viewing. (This is also the case regardless of whether I have just the text input or the input with a button -which I chose to use later)

My second problem is that while trying to set the layout of the bar my search box wont come move into the correct position when I test it in Mozilla. It [works in](http://plnkr.co/edit/xFuktTOqoeG20ak44YQ3?p=preview) my fiddle test but this is not at all what it looks like in my browser. I have already tried many of the commonly given solutions but nothing has worked so far.

```
<div id="card-search-controls" class="row">
<div class="input-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="form-control" value="Search for..." ng-model="searchFilterInput" autofocus>
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button></span>
</div>
<div class="search-results col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">TEST TEXT</div>
<div class="adv-menu col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">####</div>
</div>
```

Edit to show the css

```
#card-search-controls{
height: 50px;
margin-left: 0px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(6,25,51, 0.8);
z-index: 1;
display: flex;
}
.input-group{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#card-search-controls div{
border: 1px solid white;
}

.search-results{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: for you first question remove the input-group class from the div

Comment: I do not understand the second issue..but I test both firefox and chrome, work well check the code snippet below..

Comment: Oh great! thanks alot. Can you link me to something that explains why it works in form but not div? Also what I meant by the second questions is for example if I make the bottom search bar 50px height and the search box 30px for example then try to put 10px margin on top and bottom the search bar always sits on the bottom of the screen, no matter what I do.

Comment: for the first question when you keep "input-group" to a div it turns to block container and reserved the full row. so do not make container as a input group...

Comment: for the second question there can be many reasons so can you provide me the issue you faced..(code) so I can check..

Comment: @pTi I added the css. Basically the issue I am having is 1) that in my actual browser the search input box would not show up in the center vertically of its surrounding container. (2) the text I used to test the other two lower bar divs will not move from the top of the div. often when I change any property the search box will just sit on the very bottom of the browser screen with no space for margin. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: for the 1st question change margin-top: 8px; in .input-group and for the 2nd on I don't understand what you are saying mainly "two lower bar divs" and "often when I change any property the search box will just sit on the very bottom of the browser screen with no space for margin" @Thumper

Comment: I mean the text from .search-results and .adv-menu No matter what selectors I pick the actual output in these div won't move to where I try to put it. For instance I want the text from .search-results div to be centered vertically. And if I put 8px or anything else for the .input-group one it pushes the box down against the bottom edge of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code..I have added the input-group into separate form tag and wrapped the input field.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="card-search-controls" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
      <form class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="form-control" value="Search for..." ng-model="searchFilterInput" autofocus="" />       
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
        </span>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="search-results col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">TEST TEXT</div>
    <div class="adv-menu col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3">######</div>
  </div>
</div>
```